# video view error (can't play this video) what is wrong with my code?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying to access the video file under assets folder. But When I run this, it shows error message(can't play this video file). I doubt something wrong with path.

```
videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        videoView.setVideoPath("file:///android_asset/testdoc.mp4");
videoView.start();
```

Comment: Is that a valid video? I have a doubt whether it is playing in any other player, as it names testdoc.. :P

Comment: it's an `mp4` ... that's a valid video file extension

Comment: Better check with a different video, if problem repeats then its be a path fault, as per my knowledge there is no problem with path.

Comment: it's a valid video, I've also tried with other valid video. Problems occur the same. So I think the problem is file path.

Comment: Try to do this with a `MediaPlayer`

Answer (score 0):

Use raw folder rather than asset:

```
String videoPath = android.resource://+ getPackageName() +/raw/testdoc";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
```